# C# AssemblyVersion causing issues during app deployment. Best practices?

Tags: c#, git, deployment

We have a challenge that faces us during deployments and I've looked for best practices/solutions online but have not found anything that stuck out as a good idea yet.

### Background on Us

- We version our app in AssemblyInfo.cs using `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.3.*")]`
- We use Git and follow Git Flow for our branching strategy.

### Our Dev/Testing Process

- Sprint 8 ends and Dev team has a build for QA and if it passes then it'll get promoted to Staging and eventually Production envrionments.
- Lead developer cuts a release branch (named "release/2.3") in Git and Publishes the web app using the "Development" release configuration.  This build is assigned version 2.3.1234.56789 (provided by the AssemblyVersion).  The developer let QA know that 2.3.1234.56789 is ready to test.  The Dev team continues to work on the its work in Sprint 9 in the 'develop' branch
- The release candidate passes QA and the QA teams gives the thumbs up on 2.3.1234.56789.

### Here is where our problem begins....

We now have to cut a new release from the "release/2.3" branch using our "Production" release configuration so our code so our app will work in our Staging environment which mirrors Production.  If we publish the application again and we choose the "Production" release configuration then the AssemblyVersion changes.  This is an issue because QA validated and passed 2.3.1234.56789.

This new release might be 2.3.1236.98765 and gets a lot of attention when we say we're pushing a version of the app to Staging that wasn't signed off on by QA.

How would you handle this challenge?  We can't be blazing new trails here.  This must be a problem that has been solved one million times but I haven't seen anything relevant.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Those auto-generated numbers are actually time stamps, so if you use `2.3.*` in your assembly info, you will always have this problem.

Comment: I have seen they reflect the number of days since Jan 1 2000.  I've looked for ways to publish both of our 'Development' and 'Production' configurations simultaneously to hopefully get the same version numbers but that doesn't seem doable.

Comment: The only thing you can do is not use `*` for the third part of the version number. In fact, you may want to look at http://semver.org/ as a more structured way to do it. Since you manually change the `Y` of `X.Y.Z`, why not also manually do the `Z` too? Feel free to leave the * for the last part but let people know it doesn't affect code content and is only the date the build happened.

Comment: I suppose once i cut a release branch I could manually set the release number to X.Y.Z as you mentioned and just manage it manually in that branch from that point on.  How do most companies handle this? Do they not get hung up on version numbers?  Is there a better strategy?